# Graph DFS & BFS

Tags: data-structures, graph

Please help me with BFS and DFS for below graph starting from vertex 1 where vertices adjacent to node are visited by increasing order

[image]

**This is not a homework question.**

Comment: Help you out in what way? You're going to have to be more specific and show us what you've done and how the results differ from what you expect.

Comment: I would like to know the results of breadth first and depth first search of above graph. Please, let me know If i am not clear.

Comment: This is the result I got BFS - 1,2,3,4,5,7,6,8  & DFS - 1,2,4,3,6,8,5,7

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the order of traversal is "closest number that is increasing" then:
DFS: 1 2 4 3 6 8 5 7
BFS: 1 2 3 4 5 7 6 8